# Symfony: Firewalls, multiple login forms

Tags: symfony

I am not new to symfony by any means, but I've always used `FOSUserBundle` which by default prevents one from having 2 different login forms for authenticating two different user types..

I have two entities, one is `Admins` and the other is `Users`.  Admins will only be able to login in the administration area and likewise users will only be able to login via the front end.

I've followed:  http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/security.html  which also lead me to http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html

My security.yml is:

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true

security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: sha512
        Fm\AdminBundle\Entity\Admins: sha512
        Fm\MainBundle\Entity\Users: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [in_memory, admin]
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                    admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

        admin:
            entity: { class: Fm\AdminBundle\Entity\Admins, property: username }


    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
            anonymous: true

        alogin:
            pattern:  ^/admin/login
            security: false
        login:
            pattern:  ^/login
            security: false
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/admin
            anonymous: false
            provider: chain_provider
            switch_user: true
            form_login:
                check_path: /admin/login_check
                login_path: /admin/login
            logout:
                path:   /admin/logout
                target: /admin
        members_area:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: false
            form_login: ~
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /
            #anonymous: ~
            #http_basic:
            #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

In my routes I have defined the routes as in the docs: (defaults to /admin/login and /admin/login_check because of my main routing include where /admin is set)

```
_admin_login:
    pattern:   /login
    defaults:  { _controller: FmAdminBundle:Security:login }

_admin_login_check:
    pattern:   /login_check
```

The error that I am getting in the browser is:

`Unable to find the controller for path "/admin/login_check". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration?`

The stack trace is telling me:  `WARNING - Unable to look for the controller as the "_controller" parameter is missing`

AND

`ERROR - Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: Unable to find the controller for path "/admin/login_check". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration? (uncaught exception) at /var/www/mysite.dev/symfony/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 1419`

Comment: This is a simple regex-problem. Try `^/admin/login$` in your alogin-firewall to prevent login_check from not being behind a firewall. edit: The same goes for login of coure

Comment: That 'seems' to work, though i believe in my security.yml having the ` provider: chain_provider` should make it so that i can use the in_memory and the admin providers (as that's whats listed)...  if i put in the username admin with the password admin pass -- it redirects back to the login screen with an error of "Bad Credentials" (i have no users in the database at the moment). Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you used the correct password, it should be `adminpass`, not `admin pass`. Also, check your logs for messages from Symfony's Security-component to see if everything works as expected.

Comment: it was because of the sha512 on one of the things...  I changed that to just a single iteration sha and encoded the password and it's working...  Problem now, is that after i login it redirects me to domain.com/login instead of domain.com/admin

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For implementing multiple login in symfony 2XX, try the following code

### Security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        Company\AngularBundle\Entity\User: plaintext
        Company\AngularBundle\Entity\Admin: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
       users:
           entity: { class: CompanyAngularBundle:User, property: username }
       admin:
           entity: { class: CompanyAngularBundle:Admin, property: username }

    firewalls:
        admin_secured_area:
            pattern:   ^/admin
            anonymous: ~
            provider: admin
            form_login:
                login_path: /admin/login
                check_path: /admin/login_check
                default_target_path: /admin

        user_secured_area:
            pattern:   ^/
            anonymous: ~
            provider: users
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login_check
                default_target_path: /home
```

### routing.yml

```
login_check:
    path: /login_check
admin_login_check:
   path: /admin/login_check
```

### Twig file

```
Action of login form should be like this
<form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">

Action of admin/login form should be like this
<form action="{{ path('admin_login_check') }}" method="post">
```

Comment: Newbie mistake/gotcha: Note that if you have ^/ and ^/admin, the more specific pattern (^/admin) must be above the more general pattern ^/ in the file or else it won't take precedence since ^/ can still match ^/admin - at least, that's what finally made this work in my app where I also have a ^/ pattern in security.yml and I didn't realize that's how yml deals with regex precedence.

Comment: how did u solve that i have problem with the pattern.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that after logging into the "secured_area" firewall you get redirect to "/" which is behind the "members_area" firewall. You can't access "members_area" with your credentials from "secured_area" (at least not by default). Read the details on http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#reference-security-firewall-context .

If you have a look at the security configuration (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html) you can see that the default_target_path for form_login is "/". Just change this to /admin:

```
security:
    ...

    firewalls:
    ...
        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/admin
            ...
            form_login:
                check_path: /admin/login_check
                login_path: /admin/login
                default_target_path: /admin
            logout:
    ...
```

The alternative is to share the context as described in the first link (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#reference-security-firewall-context).