# Redirecting based on current url in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8, symfony-routing

I've got a symfony 2 application with 3 different roles: Admin, Vendor, and User.  All three of these users should have different login pages.  What I'm struggling with is figuring out what to put in the `security.yml` to get unauthenticated (`IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`) users on a certain url path `/vendor` for instance to redirect to something like `/adminlogin` versus just `/login`.  I'm using `FOSUserBundle` right now, and it looks like everything redirects to `/login`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could split the security configuration into three different firewalls: one for admin users, one for vendor users and one for other users.
And, based on URL that user hits, you should redirect him to appropriate login form (if he is not logged in).

For example, if user visits `example.com/admin/inventory`, and he is not authenticated, you should redirect him to `example.com/adminlogin`

```
firewalls:
    admin_secured_area:
        pattern:   ^/admin
        ...
        form_login:
            login_path: /admin/login
            check_path: /admin/login_check
            default_target_path: /admin

    vendor_secured_area:
        pattern:   ^/vendor
        ...
        form_login:
            login_path: /vendor/login
            check_path: /vendor/login_check
            default_target_path: /vendor

    default:
      ...
```

Please take a look at this answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24546275/5431686